# Device with OS3.0 not being detected after Xcode upgrade to 3.2.3 with OS4.0 SDK

Tags: ios4

I have recently upgraded XCode to 3.2.3 with 0S4.0 SDK. Now, after upgrading the setup, one of my device is not being detected by XCode.
In the Organizer window, the device is displayed with a yellow status and XCode complains of "The version of iPhone OS on “” is too old for use with this version of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below."

OS installed on device : 3.0 (7A341)

XCode Supported iPhone OS Versions: 4.0.1, 4.0, 3.2.1(7B405), 3.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.

My question is that if the XCode supports 3.0 version, then why the device is not being detected by the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

try restarting your mac os and power off and on your iphone